# Exclude duplicated products from query

Tags: sql

I have products table (products can be duplicated by `name` but have unique `id`), as example:
products

```
id, name, isfolder
1, Product1, 0
2, Product2, 0
3, Product3, 0
4, Product1, 0
```

In result query I want have:

```
1, Product1, 0
2, Product2, 0
3, Product3, 0
```

It is possible?

Сlarification. ID is uniqueidentifier, and I need ID in result set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by`:

```
select min(id), name, isfolder
from products p
group by name, isfolder;
```